# OOP Laravel parsing data fetched from DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Got a `OOP theory` question here, since i'm new to this kinda stuff, coming from mostly a JS flow.

Let's say i have a controller and method `MyController::getAllData` .It uses eloquent to fetch 2 different types of datasets that have almost no relations (and they shouldn't). After fetching i need to go through a few `foreach` loops and parse the data so that i don't overcrowd and clutter my neat and tidy blade files (i'm talking about 200 lines worth of data parsing).

So my question is should i create a new `private function` inside the `MyController` which will parse the data or should i create a `Helper` for this, or a 3rd way? I'm looking for the most correct way of doing this from a Laravel/PHP OOP point of view.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [ressources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) ?

Comment: The best practice for response data. you might need to use laravel API resource.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the format of data you want to get...

For paginated data use

```
\App\Example::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```

To fetch specific fields from the db use (Append the only fields you want to get)

```
\App\Example::get('first', 'second')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Do you think the second query is working @slimgera00?

Comment: Oh you need to pass in the number of records per page in the paginate helper... Like so paginate(20)